# How to make built-in ethernet work on stm32f407?

Tags: stm32, ethernet

I'm using xcore407i with stm32f407 and DP83848 phy via RMII interface, and i'm using libopencm3.

Reading/writing phy registers works fine, but sending packets doesn't work at all.

I enable RCC for ETHMACRXEN, ETHMACTXEN, ETHMACEN. Also i have tried reset MAC via RCC.

I have found, that problem is with ETH DMA. Writing 1 to ETH_DMABMR_SR should reset it, and after reset this bit is cleaned by hardware. But this doesn't happen. The same thing with ETH_DMAOMR_FTF. It should clean FIFO and return to 0. But it also infinitely =1.

When i try to send packet, i set OWN bit in descriptor and write to ETH_DMATPDR. It also never ended.

Transmit and Receive are enabled in MACCR.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Do you have a schematic?

Comment: https://www.waveshare.com/w/upload/4/4a/XCore407I-Schematic.pdf

Answer (score 0):

The MAC peripheral reset requires the 25MHz/50MHz reference clock to be present or it will not complete.  Check that PA1 is set up in the correct alt-function mode and probe to check that the the signal is present.

Comment: This board has external 50 MHz oscillator for PHY. PA1 is configured as alt-function

https://www.waveshare.com/w/upload/4/4a/XCore407I-Schematic.pdf

Comment: PA1 is configured as alt-fn before enabling MAC

Comment: gpio_mode_setup(GPIOA, GPIO_MODE_AF, GPIO_PUPD_PULLDOWN, GPIO1 | GPIO2 | GPIO7);

gpio_set_af(GPIOA, GPIO_AF11, GPIO1 | GPIO2 | GPIO7);

gpio_set_output_options(GPIOA, GPIO_OTYPE_PP, GPIO_OSPEED_100MHZ, GPIO1 | GPIO2);

Answer (score 0):

Problem was in disabled clock for SYSCFG register